# how to make a class active on another page by click link in another page in html

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have one doubt can i have an anchor tag in demo1.html page if i click that link it has to got to demo2.html page. In demo2.html page i am using a data filter and it has to select that filter can we do like that.
Here is the sample code i amm using

**Demo1.html**

```
<a href="careers.html">Bangalore </a> | <a href="#"> Mumbai </a>
```

**Demo2.html**

```
<ul>
    <li class="filter"><a class="selected" href="#0" data-type="all">All</a></li>
    <li class="filter" data-filter=".bangalore"><a href="#0" data-type="bangalore">Bangalore</a></li>
    <li class="filter" data-filter=".mumbai"><a href="#0" data-type="mumbai">Mumbai</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li class="mix bangalore"></li>
    <li class="mix mumbai"></li>
</ul>
```

I am using this [filter](http://codyhouse.co/demo/content-filter/index.html) plugin. kindly help me out with this

Answer (score 0):

First, make a function to get a querystring parameter like in [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Then update your links to

```
<a href="careers.html?dataType=bangalore">Bangalore </a> | <a href="#"> Mumbai </a>
```

and finally, target your elements in the new page

```
$('li.filter').filter(function(){
    return $(this).attr('data-type') == getParameterByName('dataType');
}).addClass('active');
```

Comment: Thanks AmmarCSE for the quick reply. can you same explain me in detail how to do this, I din't get your point clearly

Comment: @RajtheStarter, the first step is to update your anchor elements with the query string like ?dataType=bangalore

Comment: @RajtheStarter, the next step is to add the funciton getParameterByName to the Demo2.html and use it by filtering like the last code snippet in the answer